# getaddrinfo with AI_NUMERICHOST

Tags: c, linux, dns, posix

The POSIX `getaddrinfo()` function is used to perform DNS resolution, as well as service name resolution.  The `hints` argument passed to `getaddrinfo()` has a flags field, `ai_flags`.

Among the possible flag values is `AI_NUMERICHOST`.  According to [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), this informs `getaddrinfo()` that the hostname string is an IP address.  Since the hostname is already an IP address (as opposed to a hostname), no DNS resolution is necessary.

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose or use-case of this flag.  If you already have the IP address, why would you even need to call `getaddrinfo()`?  The only possible purpose I could see would be a case where you already have the IP address, but just want to get the service name.  But in that case, you could just call `getservbyname()` directly, which would be much simpler.

The only thing I can think of is that `getaddrinfo()` is re-entrant, whereas apparently `getservbyname()` is not re-entrant.  So is the entire purpose of the `AI_NUMERICHOST` flag simply to provide a round-about way of doing a thread-safe `getservbyname()`?

If not, what is the purpose of `AI_NUMERICHOST`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary use of `getaddrinfo` with `AI_NUMERICHOST` is to be an IPv4/IPv6-agnostic replacement for `inet_aton` and `inet_pton`.  That is, it takes textual IPv4 *and* IPv6 addresses and converts them to `sockaddr` objects; calling code doesn't have to know which is which.

It's also true that you can use it as a thread-safe `getservbyname`, but I can't recall the last time I saw code that *didn't* use `AI_NUMERICSERV`, so I don't think that's the important property.

Comment: Ah... very interesting.  I had thought the most important usage was for DNS resolution

Comment: Well, yes, but it's the same principle -- `getaddrinfo` _without_ `AI_NUMERICHOST` is the IPv4/v6 neutral replacement for `gethostbyname`.

Comment: Note that it's also superior to inet_pton in that it can handle IPv6 scope identifiers for link-local addresses without the caller needing to be aware such a thing exists.

Comment: @R.. This is true, but I think `getaddrinfo` automatically detecting whether it has been passed a v4 or v6 address is more practically useful. `inet_pton` _can_ parse v6 addresses but you have to tell it to do that, so the caller has to do some parsing itself still.

Comment: @zwol: I wouldn't be surprised if some people just try `inet_pton` as both and retry as the other on error...